# Dimension of the set of bounded real valued functions

Tags: functions

Assume T is infinite. What is the dimension of B(T)?

Where B(T) is the set of bounded real valued functions defined on some non-empty subset T of R (real numbers).

Comment: If $T$ is uncountable the dimension $D$ is $2^{|T|}$ where $|T|$ is the cardinal of $T.$  In ZFC, if $\aleph_0<|T|<|\Bbb R|$ then the most we can say about $D$ is $|\Bbb R|\le D\le 2^{|\Bbb R|}.$

Answer (score 0):

It's also infinite. However the cardinality may be far greater.

For any $t\in T$ consider the function $\delta_t (x) = \cases{1 & $x=t$\\ 0 & else }$

It is not hard to show that the set $\{\delta_t , t\in T\}$ is an independent set of elements in $B(T)$. Indeed, if there exist $c_1,...,c_n$ and $t_1,...,t_n$ such that $c_1\delta_{t_1}(x)+...+c_n\delta_{t_n}(x)=0$ then if you substitute $x=t_i$ we get $c_i=0$ (do this for all $1\leq i \leq n$).

However since $T$ is infinite this set is not generating, for example the constant $1$ is not a (finite) linear combination of elements in $\delta_t$.